# Is it a good practice to use self invoking anonymous function in Perl?

Tags: perl

It is a common practice to use self invoking anonymous functions to scope variables etc. in JavaScript:

```
;(function() {
  ...
})();
```

Is it a good practice to use such functions in Perl ?

```
(sub {
  ...
})->();
```

Or is it better for some reason to use main subroutine ?

```
sub main {
  ...
}

main();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has lexical scoping mechanisms JS lacks. You are better off simply enclosing code you want scoped somehow in a block, e.g.:

```
{
    my $localvar;
    . . .
}
```

In this case `$localvar` will be completely invisible outside of those braces; that is also the same mechanism one can use to localise builtin variables such as `$/`:

```
{
    local $/ = undef;
    #reading from a file handle now consumes the entire file
}
#But not out here
```

(Side note: never set `$/` globally. It can break things in subtle and horrible ways if you forget to set it back when you're done, or if you call other code before restoring it.)

In perl, the best practise is to put things in subs when it makes sense; when it doesn't make sense or unnecessarily complicates the code, lexical blocks ensure scoping; if you do need anonymous subroutines (generally for callbacks or similar) then you can do `my $subref = sub { . . . };` or even just stick the sub declaration directly into a function argument: `do_something(callback => sub { . . . });`

**Note:** see also [ysth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20289555/is-it-a-good-practice-to-use-self-invoking-anonymous-function-in-perl/20289706#20290018) for a resource-related advantage to self-invoking anonymous subs.

Answer (score 4):

Since perl provides lexically scoped variables (and, as of 5.18, lexical named subs), there is no scoping reason for doing that.

The only reason to do it that I can think of would be for memory management; if the sub in question is a closure (references at least one external lexical variable), any memory used by the sub will be totally freed instead of retained for reuse on the next call:

```
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -wle'sub { my $x; Dump $x; $x = 42 }->() for 1..2'
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x944a88
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
SV = IV(0x944a78) at 0x944a88
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
  IV = 42
$ perl -MDevel::Peek -wle'my $y; sub { $y if 0; my $x; Dump $x; $x = 42 }->() for 1..2'
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x259d238
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x259d220
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY)
```

Though if you are not concerned about memory, this would be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

It's not unheard of but not common either. To restrict variable scope temporarily, it's much more common to use a block with a `my` variable declaration:

```
...
{
    my $local_variable;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, self-invoking functions have two uses:

1. Variable scoping. The `var` declarations are hoisted into the scope of the first enclosing function or into global scope. Therefore,

   ```
   function () {
     if (true) {
       var foo = 42
     }
   }
   ```

   is the same as

   ```
   function () {
     var foo
     if (true) {
       foo = 42
     }
   }
   ```

   – often an unwanted effect.
2. Statements on the expression level. Sometimes you need multiple statements to compute something, but want to do so inside an expression.

   ```
   largeObject = {
     ...,
     // sum from 1 to 42
     sum: (function(n){
       var sum = 0;
       for(var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
         sum += i;
       return sum;
     })(42),
     ...,
   };
   ```

Perl has no need for self-invoking functions as a scoping mechanism, because a new scope is introduced by any curly brace. A bare block is always allowed on a statement level:

```
...
my $foo = 10;
{
  my $foo = 42;
}
$foo == 10 or die; # lives
```

Perl has reduced need for self-invoking functions to introduce statements into an expression because of the `do BLOCK` builtin:

```
%large_hash = (
  ...,
  sum => do {
    my $sum = 0;
    $sum += $_ for 1 .. 42;
    $sum;
  },
  ...,
);
```

However, you will sometimes want to short-curcuit in such a block. As `return` exits the surrounding subroutine (not block), it can be quite useful here. For example in a memoized function:

```
# moronic cached division by two
my %cache;
sub lookup {
  my $key = shift;
  return $cache{$key} //= sub {
    for (1 .. 100) {
      return $_ if $_ * 2 == $key
    }
    return;
  }->();
}
```